# How to insert text files in SQLite Database file?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am sorry If my question was vague, Actually I am adding bunch of text files in the local storage as logs.
I was wondering if there is a way to add these text files data into SQlite database.
I am very much new to this, thus I have limited idea about SQLite.
any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thankyou !!

Comment: You can add as much text to an SQLite database field as you like. There is no limit.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak Thankyou for the reply, I am adding my text files to a specific path in local storage, can I extract the same text files from that specific path and add it into sSQLite db file ?

Comment: Seems a waste to safe them both in the file system and in the database. Why not just safe the location of the file in the database?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have a feeling that your question actually is not *"Can I?"* but *"How can I?"*, but those are completely different questions.

Comment: Read your file, convert it to UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded unicode if needed, insert it as a text value into the database.